# Azure ARM Deployment Error Missing master

Tags: azure

I am working on setting up 3 resource groups dev/uat/prod and was looking for a way to use ARM deployment to keep the environments the same. I export the ARM template and export and I get the following error as my first error.

```
  'edapdserver/master/Default' failed with message '{
    11:23:06 -   "error": {
    11:23:06 -     "code": "ParentResourceNotFound",
    11:23:06 -     "message": "Can not perform requested operation on nested resource. Parent resource 'dserver/master' not 
    11:23:06 - found."
    11:23:06 -   }
    11:23:06 - }'
```

Then when I look at the json it exports I can only see the database that I created there not master.

```
{
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases",
      "apiVersion": "2022-02-01-preview",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('servers_edapdserver_name'), '/my-database')]",
      "location": "eastus",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('servers_dserver_name'))]"
      ],
      "sku": {
        "name": "Basic",
        "tier": "Basic",
        "capacity": 5
      },
      "kind": "v12.0,user",
      "properties": {
        "collation": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS",
        "maxSizeBytes": 2147483648,
        "catalogCollation": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS",
        "zoneRedundant": false,
        "readScale": "Disabled",
        "requestedBackupStorageRedundancy": "Geo",
        "maintenanceConfigurationId": "/subscriptions/??/providers/Microsoft.Maintenance/publicMaintenanceConfigurations/SQL_Default",
        "isLedgerOn": false
      }
    }
```

This is where the code fails

```
{
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/securityAlertPolicies",
      "apiVersion": "2022-02-01-preview",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('servers_edapdserver_name'), '/master/Default')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('servers_edapdserver_name'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "state": "Disabled",
        "disabledAlerts": [
          ""
        ],
        "emailAddresses": [
          ""
        ],
        "emailAccountAdmins": false,
        "retentionDays": 0
      }
    },
```

edit this is the server part:

```
{
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
      "apiVersion": "2022-02-01-preview",
      "name": "[parameters('servers_edapdserver_name')]",
      "location": "eastus",
      "kind": "v12.0",
      "properties": {
        "administratorLogin": "??",
        "administratorLoginPassword": "??",
        "version": "12.0",
        "minimalTlsVersion": "1.2",
        "publicNetworkAccess": "Enabled",
        "restrictOutboundNetworkAccess": "Disabled"
      }
    },
```

Comment: maybe you don't have access to master database.  This is only going to get the database itself, not the schema of the database.  Is that what you want or are you trying to get schema changes(i.e. column added)?

Comment: I am not sure I am following I created the server and the database I am the owner. All I am trying to do is deploy that template to another resource group. I am not trying to alter the database at all as that I do from SSDT

Comment: are you providing the sql server name parameters('servers_edapdserver_name')?  Or do you want a new server created?  I haven't done this with a sql database but on other resources.

Comment: I am providing everything that it needs. I exported this straight out of a working resource group